# Filter file on dates that could be anywhere in a particular column

Tags: regex, awk

Let's say I have a file with two columns:

```
blahblah2020-02-03_moreblah | VALUE |
blah2021-03-04blah | VALUE |
```

Using awk I need to select just those rows where the date in the first column is less than some other date I have. The annoying thing is the date could be among any weird strings on either side, or none at all - but it will be of the format YYYY-mm-dd. I'm not sure how I ended up in a situation where I have to use awk to this but here I am and I'm very thankful in advance!

Comment: please update the question to show some data where the date is in the 2nd column (per your comment *'could be among any weird strings on either side'*), the code you've tried and the (wrong) output generated by your code

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify, the date will always be in the first column. The second column is irrelevant - I just included it to make the data look a bit more like a table.

Comment: As for what I've tried already, I'm still struggling to just add the dates to a new column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- dates will always be of the format `YYYY-MM-DD` (confirmed in OP's description)
- any dates of interest will only reside in the 1st `|`-delimited field
- the 1st field will only contain at most one date string (ie, don't have to worry about the 1st field containing more than one date string)

Using `GNU awk 4.0` (or newer) for `FPAT` support:

```
awk -v testdt="${dt}" '                                        # pass bash variable "dt" in as awk variable "testdt"
BEGIN { FPAT="[12][0-9]{3}-[012][0-9]-[0123][0-9]"             # define pattern we are looking for; if exists it should be field #1
#       FPAT="[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}"    # one of a few alternatives
      }

$1 < testdt                                                    # if we have a match for FPAT and less than testdt then echo entire line to stdout
' input.dat
```

**NOTE:** if the input could have data of the format `####-##-##` that aren't valid dates then OP may need to tweak the `FPAT` defintion and/or add more logic to validate a match as an actual date before running the test (`$1 < testdt`)

Using OP's 2-line sample input here are some results using different values for the (`bash`) variable `dt`:

```
$ dt='2019-06-01'
$ awk -v testdt="${dt}" 'BEGIN {FPAT="[12][0-9]{3}-[012][0-9]-[0123][0-9]"} $1 < testdt' input.dat
       -- no output --

$ dt='2020-06-01'
$ awk -v testdt="${dt}" 'BEGIN {FPAT="[12][0-9]{3}-[012][0-9]-[0123][0-9]"} $1 < testdt' input.dat
blahblah2020-02-03_moreblah | VALUE |

$ dt='2021-06-01'
$ awk -v testdt="${dt}" 'BEGIN {FPAT="[12][0-9]{3}-[012][0-9]-[0123][0-9]"} $1 < testdt' input.dat
blahblah2020-02-03_moreblah | VALUE |
blah2021-03-04blah | VALUE |
```

Comment: If I create a input.dat file out of the data I posted, this code returns nothing for me with each of the three dates you used. I'm puzzled as to how that could happen since you clearly had it working? EDIT: It looks like I've mawk 1.3.4 and not the new awk I need.

Comment: @CClarke please see the updated answer; I actually replaced the 3 dots (thinking someone might not understand that was a shortcut for the complete `awk` script listed earlier in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk, in any shell, on every Unix box:

```
$ awk -v tgt='2020-05-01' 'match($0,/[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}/) && (substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) < tgt)' file
blahblah2020-02-03_moreblah | VALUE |

$ awk -v tgt='2021-05-01' 'match($0,/[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}/) && (substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) < tgt)' file
blahblah2020-02-03_moreblah | VALUE |
blah2021-03-04blah | VALUE |
```

Answer (score 0):

\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d
https://regexone.com/
it works but there are better solutions
if u want it less than write a script usually in pyhton with this regex syntax by collecting all dates and then filtering based on position before - whether thats greater than or less than the date u have.
for i in range date:
if date[i] < regex

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There are no mandatory POSIX tools and no versions of awk that would understand that regexp. Only tools are great for producing/validating regexps that work **in that online tool** but their usefulness for running regexps in command-line tools is marginal.